# K-Median constraints - FLP Linear Programming

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, constraints

I'm attempting to solve a problem using linear programming. I have been using [this resource (k-median problem midway down the page)](https://scipbook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/flp.html) as a reference.

I have successfully implemented a first attempt using Python and the PuLP library, however as I develop the model I would like to understand the meaning of the constraints more clearly.

I have provided screenshots of the problem described on the page linked above, with annotations of my understanding of each constraint.

Image 1: [Problem description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fl2eF.png) 
Image 2: [Problem constraints with my understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fp0Vx.png)

Could anyone tell me what the purpose of the final constraint is? My understanding of the formula is that the sum of *customers* being served by a single *site* can only be ≤ 1, and therefore each *site* can only serve at most one *customer* - but that's clearly not the case.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the linked page has some text missing, as well as a typo in the constraint.  I suspect that before the last constraint, the intended text was something like the following:

> As an alternative formulation, you can replace the $x_{ij} \le y_j$ constraints with the aggregated constraints $\sum_{i=1}^n x_{ij} \le n y_j$.

Note the $n$ coefficient.

Although this aggregated formulation does yield a weaker formulation, state-of-the-art solvers will generate the stronger constraints dynamically as needed.

Answer (score 2):

The last constraint (which probably has a typo) is not necessary, it is redundant with respect to

\begin{align}
x_{ij}&\le y_j \quad &(1) \\
\sum_{j}x_{ij}&=1  \quad &(2)
\end{align}

You can remove it. It might have an impact on computation times.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Kuifje. I removed the constraint and the program returned the same result as before (it took about 5% longer to solve). I'm still a bit confused though. You refer to the last constraint as ∑≤ but is it not $\Sigma_{i} x_{ij} ≤ y_{j} $ which for me contradicts constraint (2) as you refer to it.

Comment: Yes, sorry for that, I got mixed up because the constraint probably has a typo.